# Java JDBC connection pool library choice in 2011/2012?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp, bonecp

Which JDBC connection pool library should I use for a new application project (not web application)?

- Apache DBCP has [enough unresolved issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&pid=12310469&sorter/field=issuekey&sorter/order=DESC&status=1&status=4) which are pushed until 2.0 I think.
- [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0) development seems to be stopped.
- And both of them [looks relatively slow](http://jolbox.com/).
- [Proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/) is dead.
- [DBPool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/) has almost no community (at least I've found no public one - no forums, no mailing lists...)
- [Apache Tomcat Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) looks to be unusable without Tomcat
- I've found [SQL Datasources](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) article at Oracle website, but it seems, that it can be applied only to applets running in containers like servlets and web services.

Should I choose [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) may be? I don't have any huge requirements. I just need a good and easy to use database connection pool, that is in active development. Library, whose author can respond to bug reports, answer some specific question etc.

BTW, actually, I'm using MySQL only. I've found, that MySQL driver [supports DriverManager](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager) interface, but I'm unsure if it actually pools connections or not.

Comment: Why does "*Apache Tomcat Pool look to be unusable without Tomcat*"? You can download it as a separate module. And as far as I understood it, it is intended to be used outside of Tomcat as well.

Comment: c3p0 has resurrected, and is pretty active atm (https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0)

Comment: Tomcat's connection pool is definitely usable outside of Tomcat.

Comment: Great list, just what I've been looking for. One contender is missing though: [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/)

Comment: @Sergei a good remark. Just note, that Hikari is just 6 months old. I hope very much, that this project will continue to mature and will be actively developed.

Comment: in 2014 take a look at: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You've done good research. I'd say, go ahead with BoneCP. Some years ago I would have suggested c3p0, but it has currently [some open and unresolved issues](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=25357&atid=383690) as well. Too bad, actually. The BoneCP author is by the way also active [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149789/user149789) at SO.

Comment: things have changed a lot since 2 years when you first posted this answer, now I think none of the CP libraries are under active development,  could you please add an update sharing the current scenario, if possible ? what would you choose today ?

Comment: At this point I cannot recommend the current release of BoneCP (0.8). I've been running it in production for a couple of days now and it is [unacceptably](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/1243551) [buggy.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/1259257) I'd be using HikariCP if Java 7 was an option for me.

Comment: @Matt: Thank you for your feedback! Choice would anno 2013/2014 indeed be different.

Comment: as of 2014 there is a even faster DBCP than BoneCP: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Answer (score 14):

It is possible use Tomcat Connection Pool without Tomcat, it is just a couple of .jars that you can include to any software. I have successfully used Tomcat Connection Pool with [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/)  and [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) application servers.

Comment: Yes, this seem to be correct: http://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat7/docs/jdbc-pool.html#Standalone

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is [Vibur DBCP](http://www.vibur.org/). This is a new, concurrent JDBC connection pool based on Java dynamic proxies. It is fast, has concise source code, supports fairness parameter, JDBC Statement caching, long running SQL queries logging, and many other features.

Vibur DBCP is available in the central Maven repo, the website shows the needed Maven dependency, various configuration examples (with Spring, Hibernate 3.x/4.x/5.x), and all configuration options.

Vibur DBCP requires Java 1.7.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Vibur DBCP.

Answer (score 7):

I know its too late for answer but I just found an interesting [link](http://blog.trustiv.co.uk/2014/06/battle-connection-pools) which has given a broader scope to answer most your queries. But at the end **HikariCP** and **BoneCP** are much better than other options.

Comment: @FractalizeR if its good answer than it should had a great response in terms of up votes :) anyways I found it great for future use so shared  it.