# Hibernate + c3p0 + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, c3p0

I make server with HIBERNATE and SQL Server. When I use c3p0 connection pool and make load test I get lock in java (in c3p0).

In threads dump I see:

```
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.acquireStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:552)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.checkoutStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:168)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.checkoutStatement(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
   - locked <0x124d> (a com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:199)
   - locked <0x124e> (a com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
...
```

or

```
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
```

and after some time all the threads are locked.

But If I use internal hibernate connection pool - all ok. I don't see any locks. But I can't use internal hibernate connection pool because it not for production (from Hibernate docs).

Can someone help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that c3p0 is dead, you'd better use something else.
In case you use Tomcat, you can go for Apache Tomcat pool, 
otherwise, check this thread [Java JDBC connection pool library choice in 2011/2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640146/java-jdbc-connection-pool-library-choice-in-2011)

Comment: Thank you. I change c3p0 on DBCP and now all see better.