# How to use Singleton class for to get connections multiple?

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, jdbc

I wrote a Singleton class for  getting connections. However, I cannot get connections using Singleton.

I want to use my Singleton for getting several connections and to make query to database, using the connection Singleton. I always try several ways for this, and no success.

This is my Singleton class:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectDB {

private static Connection connect;
private static ConnectDB instance;

private ConnectDB()
{

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //connect DB
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip/database","root","password");

    }

    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {

        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

    }   
}

  public static ConnectDB getInstance()
  {

      if(instance == null) {

          instance = new ConnectDB();

      }

      return instance;

  }

}
```

Now, I get the connections:

```
 public class NameClass {




public void getInfoDatabase()
{   

       Connection cnn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
       PreparedStatement ps;
       ResultSet rs;

       try {

           ps = cnn.prepareStatement("select *  from tables");

           rs = ps.executeQuery();

           while(rs.next())
           {

               String tables = rs.getString("table1");
               System.out.println(tables);
           }
```

Comment: A multiple singleton? Kinda defeats the purpose of having a singleton...

Comment: where did you face a prblem? beside maby you cinsider writing a methode like execStmtL(Stmt) in the singleton class so you run it directly from here?

Comment: Where are you calling ConnectDB.getInstance() ? Not with standing that, this implementation looks broken - I don't like the look of the static Connection Object. Shouldn't that be an instance variable of ConnectDB ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use multiple connections efficiently you might be after a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool):

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database
>   connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when
>   future requests to the database are required. Connection pools are
>   used to enhance the performance of executing commands on a database.

Having a `Singleton` which will return *many* connections defies the purpose of the `Singleton`, whose task is to provide the same instance whenever it is called.

I recommend you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640146/java-jdbc-connection-pool-library-choice-in-2011-2012) previous SO thread where various connection pool libraries are discussed.

Answer (score 1):

My way is this    DBConnection is a Singleton class. And Usage of this is in ContactDAO class.

```
public class DBConnection{

    private static DBConnection instance;
    private String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.10.32:1521:orcl";
    private String login="kit";
    private String pass="1234";

    private DBConnection(){

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBConnection();
            System.out.println(" Connection  - - - - - - - -  New DBConnection created");
        }
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(instance.url, instance.login,instance.pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection)
    {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
                connection=null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> *********   ContactDAO  *************

```
public class ContactDAO {


        public List<Contact> findAll() {
            List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            Connection c = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM KIT.CONTACT";
            try {
                c = DBConnection.getConnection();
                Statement s = c.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    list.add(processRow(rs));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                DBConnection.close(c);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public List<Contact> findByCity(String city) {
            List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            Connection c = null;
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM KIT.CONTACT as e " + "WHERE UPPER(city) LIKE ? ";
            try {
                c = DBConnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, "%" + city.toUpperCase() + "%");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    list.add(processRow(rs));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                DBConnection.close(c);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public Contact findById(int id) {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM KIT.CONTACT WHERE id = ?";
            Contact contact = null;
            Connection c = null;
            try {
                c = DBConnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, id);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    contact = processRow(rs);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                DBConnection.close(c);
            }
            return contact;
        }

        public Contact save(Contact contact) {
            return contact.getId() > 0 ? update(contact) : insert(contact);
        }

        public Contact insert(Contact contact) {
            Connection c = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            try {
                c = DBConnection.getConnection();
                ps = c.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO KIT.CONTACT (country, city, address, photo,fk_user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                        new String[] { "ID" });

                ps.setString(1, contact.getCountry());
                ps.setString(2, contact.getCity());
                ps.setString(3, contact.getAddress());
                ps.setString(4, contact.getPhoto());
                ps.setInt(5, contact.getFk_user());

                ps.executeUpdate();

                ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                while(rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                contact.setId(id);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                DBConnection.close(c);
            }
            return contact;
        }

        public Contact update(Contact contact) {
            Connection c = null;
            try {
                c = DBConnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c
                        .prepareStatement("UPDATE KIT.CONTACT SET country=?, city=?, address=?, photo=?  WHERE id=?");
                ps.setString(1, contact.getCountry());
                ps.setString(2, contact.getCity());
                ps.setString(3, contact.getAddress());
                ps.setString(4, contact.getPhoto());

                ps.setInt(5, contact.getId());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("contactDAO update exception");
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                DBConnection.close(c);
            }
            return contact;
        }

        public boolean remove(int id) {
            Connection c = null;
            try {
                c = DBConnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c
                        .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM KIT.CONTACT WHERE id=?");
                ps.setInt(1, id);
                int count = ps.executeUpdate();
                return count == 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                DBConnection.close(c);
            }
        }

        protected Contact processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            contact.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
            contact.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
            contact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            contact.setPhoto(rs.getString("photo"));

            return contact;

        }







    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have a singleton class of connection pools like [ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) and then get multiple connections from that.