# MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource or c3p0 like library?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp, bonecp

What's the difference between MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource and C3p0, BoneCP or dbcp library for connection pooling? I don't understand why use a library if mysql connector give connection pooling.

Comment: Here are some more details about what might best suit your needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640146/java-jdbc-connection-pool-library-choice-in-2011-2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is **not** a connection pool (or at least: it shouldn't be), it is intended to be used by a `DataSource` that provides pooling (eg from an application server). A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` provides the physical connections that will be held in the connection pool. Besides creating those physical connections a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` shouldn't do anything else.

So if you are working in an application server, use the pooling provided by the `DataSource`s of the application server. If you are in a standalone application or a server that doesn't provide datasources on its own, use third party connection pools like BoneCP, c3p0 or Apache DBCP. If MySQL also provides a normal `DataSource` that provides pooling, then you could use that.