# Performace of c3p0 or Apache DBCP or Proxool in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, connection-pooling

As everyone Hibernate provide these Connection pools and Hibernate comes with **c3p0** connection pool.
Now if we are talking about performance which connection pooling will be good with hibernate?  We can use any connection pool but connection pool is necessary for every production use.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520585/connection-pooling-options-with-jdbc-dbcp-vs-c3p0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640146/java-jdbc-connection-pool-library-choice-in-2011-2012)

Hibernate would not include `c3p0` if it is not worth for production. Hibernate itself says:

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not
>   intended for use in a production system, or even for performance
>   testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and
>   stability. Just replace the hibernate.connection.pool_size property
>   with connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's
>   internal pool. For example, you might like to use c3p0.  C3P0 is an
>   open source JDBC connection pool distributed along with Hibernate in
>   the lib directory. Hibernate will use its
>   org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider for connection pooling
>   if you set hibernate.c3p0.* properties. If you would like to use
>   Proxool, refer to the packaged hibernate.properties and the Hibernate
>   web site for more information.

It seems both of them proxol and c3p0 are fine based on hibernate. 
DBCP is one stop solution for this problem and comes with tomcat itself, we have been using it for a long time in my company for really hight traffic web site and never had problem with it